# Not getting appropriate image after background subtraction

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I take two frames from my video .One of then is the background and the next is the frame to which I applied background subtraction.The third image is the result after background subtraction.Here I am only getting the shirt of the person rather than the whole body.

**Code for backgorund subtraction**

```
v = VideoReader('test.mp4');
n = get(v,'NumberOfFrames');
back = read(v,30);
y = read(v,150);
imshow([y;back;y-back]);
```

Comment: Please provide the original images so we can help you.  You are also not performing background subtraction properly.  This requires having a mask that denotes what is different than the reference frame and indexing into the new frame to extract out the pixels that are different.

Answer (score 0):

As white has probably a higher value (in each channel maybe? I don't know how the format of your data is). You get negative values which then I guess is cropped to 0 (black). See how your shirt is green as you subtract the red from it (board in the background).

You have to mask out the background by checking what has changed and then remove everything that hasn't changed.

maybe something like

```
diff =y-back
if ( element of diff unequal 0) then set element to 1
noback = diff .* y
```

a little example I wrote:

```
back = rand(4)
y = back
y(5) = 0.6               %put something in front of the background
y(7) = 0.7               %put something in front of the background
mask = zeros(4)
mask(find(y-back)) = 1   %set values that are different in y to 1
noback = mask.*y         %elementwise multiplication to mask out the background
```

You may have to use something other than find for the mask, because the image will not be 100% the same, but this should show the general approach.

Comment: The data type of the image is uint8.Can you explain the use of noback

Comment: `noback` should just be the picture without the background. (just like your `back`). And to attain that you just multiply each pixel with 0 or1 (a binary matrix) depending on if there are changes from back.